# Upload fails on Azure website directory

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net webapi app  hosted on azure app services. Inside that api, i have a folder called uploads where i have to upload my files.I am using Winform c# as my client to upload files in zip format.

Locally everything is working fine , but when i am deploying my solution to Azure, upload fails.

Kindly note , I knew, Blob storage and its usage but my requirement is Azure website/IIS with files inside the web directory. And access those via http rest apis.

Help me...

Comment: What does "upload fails" exactly mean? Any error message or something like that?

Comment: no , i am unable to debug my api hosted on azure. no error or exceptions just null value

Comment: Does this folder uploads exists on the Azure server? Check using Kudu?

Comment: @mitul , yes it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look @ your kudu console
yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net
Check that you have the right to write to that specific uploads directory

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload should work on azure Website directory if the directory is existed. I do a test on it. In the local I upload file to the App_Data/uploads folder, after I publish the Azure Web API I check that there is no related folder in the Website directory. So I switch to the Kudu console (https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net) website directory and create folders App_Data/uploads.

[image]

Then I use the fiddler tool to upload file with Azure upload API.

[image]

Check the upload file from the Kudu.

[image]

2. If we get error during upload file, we also could remote debug our Azure WebApi project, more details about how to remote debug Azure website please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps).