# Uploaded images not displaying after publishing on azure

Tags: azure, entity-framework, file-upload, publishing

Good day everyone I have a Web App created using Entity framework it has an upload feature and the upload feature works on localhost. Now after publishing to azure the site is working however the uploaded images are not displaying when I try to upload a new image it gave an "An error occurred while processing your request". Connection string is correct since other data are showing I changed the permission of the upload folder then republished still the same. Looking at the dev console it is showing failed to load resource. But why? Do I need to configure azure? Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: If you are storing some images on an app service and unable to access them, I think you need to expose a virtual directory by this guide : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-path-mappings

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: while this did not solve my issue it did redirect me to the right topic that I should focus on and eventually come up with a solution. Thank you Sir!

Comment: No problem, could you pls share that how you solved the issue? So that It will help others ,thanks!

Comment: I just posted it! I even attached the references thank you again sir.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was look at azure website's Kudu console (something I am not aware of) and upon looking at the Kudu console I realized that my upload directory is not included which is why the images are not loading it doesn't exist. I don't why it is not included but eventually I created a new upload directory at the kudu console and manually transfer the photos after that the photos are now displaying and upload is now working. For references: [reference 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/46900/azure-app-service-not-able-to-find-root-folder-pat.html) [reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227177/upload-fails-on-azure-website-directory)